# Enabling WOL on HP Proliant

Tags: windows-server-2012, hp-proliant, wake-on-lan

HP Proliant dl360 g7.  Two Broadcom NICs teamed LACP using Windows Server 2012 built-in teaming utility.  BIOS setting to "enable WOL" is set to enabled.  No "Power Management" tab exists in the (virtual) team adapter!

Machine will not wake when magic packet is forwarded to the MAC address of the team.  Am I missing something?  Is it possible to wake a NIC team?

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend you make use of the ILO3 interface of your HP ProLiant G7 server if you have any desire to control its power state.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice, but it's not an option for me.

Comment: @Tedwin Oh? Why not?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to wake the host.. On a older HP I had to use an unused Ethernet NIC, not teamed, and sent the packet to its MAC to wake the server. 
That may not be what you need, but ... it might help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

Wake-on-LAN is terribly inconsistent. For example, sometime the network adapter just fails to transmit the start command to the power supply.

Because of that I would strongly suggest to use the iLO adapter to power on your sever reliably, if you have the opportunity to do so. However, you stated that this is not the case so let me explain why I think that wol doesn't work in your case:

I'm not 100% sure of this but I am pretty positive that the problem is the NIC teaming. 
A NIC Team uses a virtual MAC-address. But since the server is powered off when you send the wol-packet, I don't think that the virtual MAC-address exists at that point. Sadly I couldn't find any hard proof to back this assumption.

You could try to send a wol-packet to a single NIC without teaming, to see if it works. Or address it to to the physical MAC of one of your NICs in the team. If you have to chance to do that, please let me know if it worked!